# How to get Thumbnail in Android API 29

Tags: android

Trying to get thumbnails from a video. Prior to API 29, this was managed using MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails. Code example

```
Bitmap bitmapThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoArrayList.get(position).getPath(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

But in API 29 MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails is declared deprecated. Google offers ContentResolver # loadThumbnail. Tell me how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

`createVideoThumbnail` was changed from:

> public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)

to

> public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)

---

So, the example you have provided in your question, will change to the following:

```java
Size mSize = new Size(96,96);
CancellationSignal ca = new CancellationSignal();
Bitmap bitmapThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(new File(videoArrayList.get(position).getPath()), mSize, ca);
```

You can use `CancellationSignal` to cancel the creation of the `Bitmap` by calling `ca.cancel();`.

The `Size` value depends on the size of `Bitmap` you want:

> Size: The target area on the screen where this thumbnail will be shown. This is passed to the provider as EXTRA_SIZE to help it avoid downloading or generating heavy resources. This value cannot be null.

---

You can also use `loadThumbnail`, which accepts a `Uri` instead of a `File` object, like this:

> public Bitmap loadThumbnail (Uri uri, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)

So your code will then look like this:

```java
Uri mUri = ...; // Your Uri
Size mSize = new Size(96,96);
CancellationSignal ca = new CancellationSignal();
Bitmap bitmapThumbnail = getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(mUri, mSize, ca);
```

Comment: do you know of a way to get the file path of the created thumbnail?

Comment: 0

These all end up addressing the problem of getting the thumbnail from the file. The problem we're facing is getting the file path of the resulting thumbnail. To get the path of the video thumbnail that’s passed to the app all involve re-saving the image to the filesystem, and I don’t want to do that and duplicate the media on the user’s device. Any suggestion how to get the file path (we need video duration). Thanks.

Comment: The question was "How to get Thumbnail" not how to get bitmap file path. This question has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

```
//You can use this 
val bitmapThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
            File(filePath),
            Size(120, 120),
            null)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options and here's the best way to create video thumbnail which is compatible with all API levels

```
val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
       .setDataSource("YOUR_VIDEO_URL", HashMap())
        val bitmap =
            retriever.getFrameAtTime(2000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```