# Generate Thumbnail From Sdcard in Android Q

Tags: android, video, android-10.0

I am using below method to generate thumbnail (its deprecated in android 10)

```
thumbnail_bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
```

Getting Exception like this

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create thumbnail
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096822/8199772

Comment: @HB Thank you for replay. i did implement your solution but getting path related error like : 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can't open content://com.wrlnk.provider/external_files/Movies/202011_26-102204_compress.mp4 as type image/*'

Comment: @VishalBhimani You passed the mime type `image/*` but then you pass/select a video file.

Comment: @HB i am not pass any mime type  

`Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(path));
         
            try {
                thumbnail_bitmap = getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(fileUri, mSize, ca);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`

Comment: What is `path`? How do you get `path`?

Comment: @HB this way get the Uri : 

`Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(path));`

Comment: @VishalBhimani I know that, I'm talking about `path`. Where do you get that from?

Comment: @HB 

`getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) .getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM_dd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "_compress.mp4";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solution for generate thumbnail of video from storage.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            thumbnail_bitmap = createThumbnail(RecordPitchActivity.this, path);

        } else {
            thumbnail_bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
        }
```

```
public static Bitmap createThumbnail(Activity activity, String path) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(activity, Uri.parse(path));
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: For me, below Q code is not working, returning null

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things wrong with your implementation.

The first is `createVideoThumbnail` was changed from:

> public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)

to

> public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)

---

The second is the way you retrieve your `path` and trying to convert it to a `Uri`:

```java
String path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) .getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM_dd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "_compress.mp4";

Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(path));
```

You should instead make use of `ContentValues` and  `ContentResolver` to create a `Uri`, then write to that `Uri` and insert it when done, like this:

```java
ContentValues valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/");
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1); 
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver(); 

Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY); 

Size mSize = new Size(96,96);
CancellationSignal ca = new CancellationSignal(); 
Bitmap bitmapThumbnail = getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(collection, mSize, ca);

Uri uriSavedThumb = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);
```

Comment: Which `MediaStore` you import ?  getting error `MediaStore.Image`. i think its `Images` Not `Image`

Comment: In your solution how to know which video file used to generate thumbnail  ?